# Waiting ajax success before next iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, each

I have to perform ajax requests for a specific Array and wait for the server response before proceeding to the next iteration in the loop.

I currently have my iterations performed simultaneously. How do I proceed only after ensuring the success?

Thanks for any advice.

```
myArray.each(function(val, index) {
    new Ajax.Request(myUrl + val, {
        onSuccess: function() {
               responseFromServer();
        }
    });
    void(0);
});
```

Comment: Are you using a framework which provides a promise API?  [here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx) of doing basically what you've asked.

Comment: @JimSchubert That doesn't really show how to queue them, just how to be notified when they're all finished.

Comment: @JuanMendes I think I misunderstood that Dee only wanted to wait for the success of all responses rather than performing each ajax request in serial only after the previous request has successfully completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might try it like this

```
function getItem(url, array, index)
{
   new Ajax.Request(url + array[index])
   {
      onSuccess : function()
      {
        responseFromServer(); //assuming this handles the server response
        if (index < array.length)
           getItem(url, array, ++index);
      }
   }
}
```

then just call it with

```
getItem(myUrl, myrray, 0);
```

basically, you want the callback to start the next ajaxrequest, on the next item in your array

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only thing you need to increase the value of the loop before: ++index

Answer (score 3):

You have to go to the next iteration only after the AJAX request is finished. I'll use jQuery to show an example;

```
function sendRequests(requests) {
    var value = requests.shift();
    $.ajax(myUrl + value).done(function(data){
        if (requests.length > 0) {
            sendRequests(requests);
        }
    });    
}

sendRequests( [1,2,3,4] );
```

Comment: Or, just: requests.length && sendRequests(requests);

Comment: @nekman Sure you could use that, but it's not clearer than what I have, my code is much more semantic the the trick you suggest. `var a = b && b.c` is acceptable in my mind. They way you're using it is actually prohibited by our style guideline since  (for code clarity) you shouldn't have side effects within a boolean expression

Comment: I agree with you that it is clearer. I just tend to like one-liners in JS just "because you can" :). Anyway, nice solution on the actual question/problem!

Comment: @nekman one-liners are for Perl, the "write once read never" language ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Basically, instead of iterating over all your elements, dequeue the first item from your array, and make the AJAX request.  Then, when your request is completed successfully, you invoke the next item.

Note that in this example, the original array is mutated, which may or may not be OK in your case.

```
function invokeAll(myArray)
{
    var val = myArray.shift(); //get the next item to be processed
    if (!val)
        return;
    new Ajax.Request(myUrl + val, {
        onSuccess: function() {
               responseFromServer();
               invokeAll(myArray); //got a successful response, start the next one
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class for this job, its processNext() function will process all items in array

```
var arrayProcessor = {
        values: [],
        process: function(arr) {
           arrayProcessor.values = arr;
           arrayProcessor.processNext();  
        },
        processNext: function(){
            if (arrayProcessor.values.length > 0) {
              new Ajax.Request(myUrl + arrayProcessor.values.shift(), {
                  onSuccess: function() {
                       responseFromServer();
                       arrayProcessor.processNext();  
                  }
              });
           }
        },

    }
```

Comment: What you have is not a class, it's a just a static object.

Comment: True, and as I know everything is an object in JavaScript

Comment: That's true, but you can implement class like behavior using the `prototype` object, that's what's usually referred to as a class in JS. If you can't create multiple copies of your `object`, it's not a class.